# Postfix, dovecot and Squirrelmail not receiving mails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail

I set up, following [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/)

Postfix, dovecot and Squirrelmail. I can correctly send mails but I cannot receive. I can receive mail only if I send them by myself to myself.

This is a log sending to myself an email:

```
    Mar 22 20:21:13 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap-login: Login: 
user=<dario>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=5043, 
secured, session=<AJ+qmLSElrp/AAAB>
Mar 22 20:21:13 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap(dario): Logged out 
in=44 out=831
Mar 22 20:21:14 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user= .   <dario>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=5045, 
secured, session=<soCtmLSEmLp/AAAB>
Mar 22 20:21:14 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap(dario): Logged out 
in=285 out=2216
Mar 22 20:21:14 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user= .  <dario>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=5047, secured, 
session=<IuqtmLSEmrp/AAAB>
Mar 22 20:21:14 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap(dario): Logged out 
in=117 out=1529
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/smtpd[5019]: connect from 
localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/smtpd[5019]: CA704A0E: 
client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/cleanup[5023]: CA704A0E: 
message-id=<aac2b1778d5ffcb9c36a26041c2be9cd.squirrel@mervo.io>
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/qmgr[4932]: CA704A0E: 
from=<dario@mervo.io>, size=684, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/smtpd[5019]: disconnect 
from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/local[5024]: CA704A0E: to= .   <dario@mervo.io>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0.01, 
dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 postfix/qmgr[4932]: CA704A0E: 
removed
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user= .   <dario>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=5049, 
secured, session=<H+jMmbSEnrp/AAAB>
Mar 22 20:21:32 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap(dario): Logged out 
in=592 out=572
Mar 22 20:21:33 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user= .   <dario>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=5051, 
secured, session=</MfOmbSEoLp/AAAB>
Mar 22 20:21:33 ubuntu-512mb-ams2-01 dovecot: imap(dario): Logged out 
in=292 out=2105
```

I have to admit that following the tutorial at Devcot installation did not followed the gui to set the autosigned ssl certificate so I did not set it, maybe depends on it?

**UPD:**

I have tested with pingtool and this is the result: Nmap scan report for mervo.io (185.14.185.89)

```
PORT STATE SERVICE
23/tcp filtered telnet
25/tcp filtered smtp
```

Comment: You set MX record for Your domain? port 25 (postfix/smtpd) is accessible from outside (try telnet or smtp client from external host or web tool like https://pingtool.org/#tab01)? Show log of external smtp session if any.

Comment: I have tested with pingtool and this is the result: Nmap scan report for mervo.io (185.14.185.89) 
PORT STATE SERVICE 
23/tcp filtered telnet 
25/tcp filtered smtp

Comment: Regarding to DNS I have: No DMARC Record found, DNS Record not found  
,DMARC Policy Not Enabled DMARC Quarantine/Reject policy not enabled

Comment: Better add important information in question body.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need open port 25 (with responding mail server on it). Probably it closed in ubuntu firewall or in worst case by ISP firewall.
2. Initially You need MX rcord in Your domain pointing to IP of mail server, with open port 25. About SFP, DKIM, DMARK and etc, it more important for accepting mail from Your server by third party mail servers as not a spam. It next step of configuration, after success in basic functionality.